# Mostrar cantidad de repetición de cada registro

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

quiero saber si hay alguna forma de mostrar una columna al lado de un listado la cantidad de veces que repite sin usar group by, mi código de ejemplo es`SELECT letras FROM mydb.table1;`me da el siguiente resultado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] necesito que quede así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], en el ejemplo A repite 2 veces, B no repite y C repite 3 veces, por eso me gustaría que muestre a lado de cada letra la cantidad de veces que repite, espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya gracias.

Comment: Porque sin usar group by ?... necesariamente necesitas funciones de grupo para eso.

Comment: Así me solucionaría un problema que tengo, pero si no se puede sin group by voy a ver otra forma solucionarlo, gracias

Comment: ¿Por que sin un group by?¿Es una asignación escolar/académica que te exige resolverlo de cierta forma? si es así, ¿has intentado/investigado algo?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho El problema lo plantee en este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388248/reportviewer-cantidad-de-registro-por-grupo-principal y con esta consulta lo puedo solucionar, pero ya me respondieron abajo con lo que necesito, gracias

Comment: Estupendo, pero la respuesta es mediante el uso del `group by` entonces edita tu pregunta y elimina la parte `sin usar group by`. Saludos.

Comment: Dale, ya esta..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `GROUP BY` es necesario para obtener la cantidad de veces que se repite cada letra, pero puedes obtener el resultado esperado cambiando la consulta:

Con MySQL versión 8, puedes utilizar [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) como el ejemplo siguiente:

```
WITH conteo (letras, Repite) as (
    SELECT letras, count(letras) FROM table1 group by letras 
)
SELECT table1.letras, conteo.Repite 
FROM   table1 INNER JOIN conteo ON
       table1.letras = conteo.letras
```

O una consulta equivalente que funciona en cualquier versión:

```
SELECT table1.letras, conteo.Repite 
FROM   table1 
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT letras, count(letras) as Repite FROM table1 group by letras ) AS conteo 
ON  table1.letras = conteo.letras
```

Comment: La segunda opción me funciona perfectamente, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente para eso se usa un group by, pero como mencionas en tu pregunta no lo quieres usar, ademas de las opciones que describe Pablo, puedes obtener el dato con una función, aunque para listados grandes no lo recomiendo porque el select se vuelve lento.

algo mas o menos así:

`SELECT table1.letras, dbo.f_contar_letras(table1.letras) from table1`

Y la función dbo.contar_letras seria mas o menos asi:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f_contar_letras(letraSeleccionada VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE cantidad INT;
    SET cantidad = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE letras = letraSeleccionada;
    RETURN cantidad;    
END
```

Donde dbo es el nombre del esquema o base de datos.

Comment: gracias por responder, ya me funciona con la propuesta de Pablo Gutiérrez

Comment: @DaniParedez, esta realmente es la respuesta que responde a tu pregunta, ni un +1 para rramirezech?

Comment: ya esta, pero como soy usuario nuevo me dice que re registra pero que no se va ver reflejado, algo así

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas MySQL 8.0 o superior, puedes valerte de una [función de ventana](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) para obtener el resultado.

```
select letras
       , count(1) over (partition by letras) as Repite
  from mydb.table1
```

De esta forma, no es necesario agrupar —casualmente habías pedido eso—. en realidad escribo la respuesta porque me parece que es más adecuado y probablemente hasta más óptimo realizar el cálculo de esta manera.

Comment: Gracias, voy a ver si actualizo a la versión 8.0 para usar esas funciones